# problem of creating multithreaded server

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to create a multi-client server, and I managed to secure the exchange of information between the server and a single client,
but now I have to use thread, so that multiple clients can connect at the same time with the server.

I followed the instructions on the internet, but I get an error

> '`CreateThread`': can not convert parameter 3 from '`unsigned long (void *)`' to '`unsigned long (__stdcall *) (void *)`'

you will see that in this function, I return 0, because I do not know what to return.

Here is my code:

```
#include"serveur.h"

server::server(int p)
{
port = p;

}


int server::init()
{    
WORD wVersionRequested;
WSADATA  Data;
int error= (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &Data ));

if(error != 0 )
{
    cerr <<"WSAStartup a échoué "<< endl;
    return 1;
}
else
{
        ServerAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        ServerAddr.sin_port = htons( port );   

        ServerAddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htons(INADDR_ANY) ;  
}

cout <<"server correctement initialise" << endl;    
return 0;   
}

DWORD WINAPI server::ClientThread(void * p)
{

    struct thread_param *Obj = (struct thread_param      *) p ;
    server *s = Obj->ser;       

    cout << "thread client start" << endl;


char buffer[100];
        //**** sent ****

            strcpy(buffer, "coucou \n");
            send(Obj->soc, buffer,strlen(buffer), 0);
            cout<<"message envoye"<<endl;

    int reponse = 0;    
        do
        {
        //  cout<<"******** reception ...********"<<endl;
            reponse = recv(Obj->soc, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
            cout<<"reponse"<<reponse<<endl;
            buffer[reponse]='\0';
            cout<<"msg recu "<<buffer<<endl;

        }while(reponse=0);


return 0;
}

int server::start ()
{
SOCKADDR_IN             ClientAddr;
int                     ClientAddrLen;
HANDLE                  hProcessThread;

struct thread_param     p;

    ListeningSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if(ListeningSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        perror("socket()");
        exit(-1);
    }
        cout <<"socket correctement creee" << endl;  
if( bind( ListeningSocket, (SOCKADDR *)&ServerAddr, sizeof( ServerAddr ) ) == SOCKET_ERROR )
    {
    cerr<<"bind a echoue avec l'erreur "<< WSAGetLastError()<< endl;
    cerr<<"Le port est peut-être deja utilise par un autre processus "<< endl;

        return 1;
    } 
            cerr<<"Bind... "<< endl;
    if( listen( ListeningSocket, 5 ) == SOCKET_ERROR )
    {
        cerr<<"listen a échoué avec l'erreur "<< WSAGetLastError()<< endl;

        return 1;
    } 

        cout <<"serveur demarre : a l ecoute du port "<<port<< endl; 
        running = true;
        ClientAddrLen = sizeof( ClientAddr );
    while(running)
    {   

if(Newconnection = accept(ListeningSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&ClientAddr, &ClientAddrLen) == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {

     cout<<"accept a echoue avec l erreur "<< WSAGetLastError() << endl;

            return 1;
        }
            p.ser=this;
            p.soc=Newconnection;
            cout<<"client connecte..."<<endl;
        hProcessThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0,ClientThread, &p,0,NULL);

        if ( hProcessThread == NULL )
        {                       
    cerr <<"CreateThread a échoué avec l'erreur "<<GetLastError()<< endl;
        }

    }

    closesocket( ListeningSocket );
            WSACleanup();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to pass a member function as a function pointer to a c-style function like this. You could use a static function that takes a pointer to `this` and then cast the object and call your member function from within the static function. Or, better yet, use [std::thread.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh852594.aspx)